# strtoul Equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, data-conversion

I'm trying to read-in a bunch of unsigned integers from a configuration file into a class. These numbers may be specified in either base-10 (eg: 1234) or in base-16 (eg: 0xAB31). Therefore looking for the `strtoul` equivalent in C# 2.0.

More specifically, I'm interested in a C# function which mimics the behaviour of the this function when the argument indicating the base or radix is passed in as zero. (Under C++, `strtoul` will attempt to 'guess' the base or radix based on the first couple of characters in the string and then proceed to convert the number suitably)

Currently I'm manually checking the first two characters (using `string.Substring()` method) of the string and then calling `Convert.ToUInt32(hex, 10)` or `Convert.ToUInt32(hex, 16)` as needed.

I'm sure that there has to be a better way to deal with this problem and hence this post. More elegant ideas/solutions or work-arounds would be great help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you don't need to use Substring unless it's in hex, but it sounds like you're basically doing it the right way:

```
return text.StartsWith("0x") ? Convert.ToUInt32(text.Substring(2), 16)
                             : Convert.ToUInt32(text, 10);
```

Obviously this will create an extra object for the `Substring` call, and you *could* write your own hex parsing code to cope with this - but unless you've actually run into performance problems with this approach, I'd keep it simple.

Comment: Thanks for the cleaner syntax. It didn't occur to me to use `StartsWith()`. I'm reading about ~50 values so a slight performance hit is OK. Also, does this mean that there is no library function to do this? (a custom/own implementation of `strtoul` in C# looks like an overkill for this small problem IMHO)

Comment: @Bhargav: It means I don't *know of* a library function to do this :)